# Cash on Delivery SCAM Germany !!!! I NEED ADVICE?

Tags: scams, germany, law, legal

Cash on Delivery SCAM !!!! Germany. I NEED ADVICE !!!!

I purchased a Mobile phone from one person worth 1000€. We agreed on the Cash on Delivery method that he will deliver the phone through DHL COD, I agreed because I feel it is safe. And thought I will receive the phone and after checking I will pay the money to the deliverer and if anything wrong happens I will refuse to take it. And DHL will send it back or make a complaint but my money will be saved at least.

As I received my parcel. immediately i opened the parcel and there were lemons inside instead of phone. and i showed it to DHL deliverer. I asked the deliverer to send it back because I was supposed to receive a phone not lemons. She refuse to take it back and said it's not my fault and said to call on the helpline and just went.

I call on DHL Helpline suddenly and ask them to stop the transaction and made a complaint about delivery, That I was supposed to receive a phone but there is lemons inside the parcel.
They said we can't do anything, contact the sender and ask what he delivered...
I said his phone is off and he blocked me from everywhere...
They said then call the police we can't do anything. We just delivered the product.
I said at least hold the money till I make a complaint to the police. if the sender will receive Money. He will disappear and there is very less chance that the police will find him because he did everything online and printed the label at home used a fake DHL account and left the parcel in the pack station somewhere, and there is no clue behind. If DHL did not transfer money into scammer's Paypal account. He will contact DHL and Police can trap and arrest him.
They don't give a shit and said sorry for that but we can not stop transferring the money to the sender. This is police's work to find the scammer, not ours. After that, I just make a complaint to the police and handed over all the proofs and the parcel to them and hoping for authorities to arrest the scammer and recover my money.

I think it was DHL responsibility as well to protect the recipient as well. its not something that happened a week or two ago, that i am complaining about. it was at the spot as I receive the parcel and i call DHL helpline.
Lets suppose if there would be a phone in the Parcel and I received it but I did'nt pay or pay less or pay with fake money to the deliverer. Then they would definitely take action against me and whatever happened DHL will pay full money to the sender. But on the other hand as a recipient, I received the wrong product in the parcel and I told them immediately but DHL said they can't do anything and I am Helpless here but the Sender received full money by doing fraud. how it could be justified by DHL???

What do you think is there any fault of DHL ??
If yes can I take any legal action against the Company !!!!
Is there any chance I could get my money Back ?
Your advice will be so helpful. Thank you in advance

Comment: It could be a useful question and would be a lot more readable if you focused on the facts and removed the rant...

Answer (score 4):

Contact eBay, as they have buyer protection policies. However, if the scammer was smart, they likely tricked you into making a purchase that wasn't covered, e.g. by transacting outside of eBay.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you already got your answer: go to the police.

The shipping company was given a package and instructed to collect payment on delivery. They delivered the package and collected the payment as instructed. Anything else is not their problem and they did nothing wrong in this situation.

Comment: Thank you for the ans but there a something I know its a police procedure but DHL should at least give some kind of protection to recipient as well. like if I buy something and I got got scamed so they could easily settled by stoping the process and not to pay money to the sender and neither to the recipient. they should ask to go the police. but they did not do it here they said we can not do anything just go to the police. and if they release the money to the sender there is a 99 percent chance money can not be recovered because he will use Paypal and a fake identity that is untraceable . ??

Comment: @StephenBey you're asking them to adjudicate the dispute between you and the seller - why would they? Their job is to deliver a package and to collect a payment, not to become an arbiter of whether a contract has been fulfilled. That's what courts are for. You *chose* to make that transaction, knowing fully well what the risks are - what exactly did you expect to happen?

Comment: This is a terrible scam, and it must hurt, but this is between you, the seller, and PayPal. Cash on delivery is just that. If you want the right to inspect the goods and possibly decline them without paying, you have to make other arrangements. DHL has no idea what your agreement with seller was, other than that the two of you agreed to send the package using DHL and pay COD for it. For all DHL knows you ordered a box of exotic lemons and are now trying to get out of the deal.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have already made a complaint to the Police. I hope they will take appropriate action and help me to recover my money. This is the worst experience of my life. 
I was aware that could be some kind of fraud could happen that why I choose cash on delivery if I will receive the scam product I could take action and DHL will not pay the sender till they verify or legal authorities verify the situation. but it opposite here they have nothing to do with the content or intention of the Sender or receiver. which means people can scam easily by using fake accounts and details.

Comment: Sorry for such a long debate but there are some points I would like to raise !!!
The sender is giving DHL 5€ to deliver whatever thing in the box to the recipient and asks DHL to pick 1000 from the recipient and if DHL delivers and not took 1000 from the recipient there is something DHL has to do against the recipient!!!
but if the receipt paid 1000€ for the package and ask them please help me out. there is something wrong. They have money in their hand and they know if someone is complaining there could be something wrong. And ask the recipient to contact to police...........

Comment: For now, we have stopped the transaction for the sender. Because it is not just my money it's a crime sender commits. 
unfortunately, even if authorities could find the sender, there will be my money saved.
they can hold it till legal action has been taken and authorities will figure out the facts because as a scammer will find out his plan is revealed he will hide and my money could be saved.
I have faced the same type of problem in Ukraine but as I ask DHL about scam delivery they tried to contact the sender and for 10 days they did not get any response from the sender............

Comment: After 10 days I received my money back. This is much easier to solve but I think some people like to make things much more complicated than actually in Germany.

Comment: I understand that this is frustrating and it's a lot of money that you've now lost. Unfortunately DHL is not at fault here, they are just the messenger, quite literally. While I empathize with you, arguing your frustration here would probably not be very productive.

Comment: @StephenBey it surely depends on the country. In some places you could refuse the delivery, but the answer is saying that in Germany you don't refuse the delivery, rather you file a police report. (I don't know whether that is correct or not)

Comment: @user253751 I'm sure refusing delivery *was* an option, but the OP didn't refuse the delivery - they accepted it, and opened the package. I can't imagine DHL employee demanding $1000 cash payment if the OP didn't want to accept the package, but I also can't imagine how DHL would be determining that what they delivered is not what the seller was supposed to be shipping, and whose fault that would be. For all we know, the seller did in fact ship a phone and a DHL employee somewhere replaced the package content. Or, the deal was for lemons and the OP is just trying to back out.

Comment: @littleadv and I'm sure in some jurisdictions, the right thing to do is open the package, inspect it, and then give it back to the courier saying this is the wrong package, sorry.

Comment: @user253751 I'm not familiar with any such jurisdiction, but feel free to add an answer.

Comment: Man absolutely, I respect your opinion. I was aware of this kind of fraud could be possible that is why I chose cash on delivery because if anything wrong happened I will refuse to take delivery and I will be saved and also report to POLICE but I got trapped. I think the scammer was aware of this if I got delivery. so there is no way I could refuse to take even whatever was inside the parcel concern to me.
and DHL didn't respond as they should do. they can only solve it by calling or sending an email to the sender about suspicious delivery and while doing that they could ask me to.........

Comment: contact the Police but instead, they said you contact the police and we could not stop Payment sorry.and even while paying money to the deliverer and opening the package I asked my friend to record the unpacking.some kind of problem with the phone or anything wrong could be happened because I was suspicious of the weight of the parcel. but as I open there were lemons inside and DHL deliverer girl was in front of me, I show her what is this. It suppose to receive a Phone, not lemons. Did I pay for Lemon? and she said I don't know. it's not my fault. and she just took 1000 and went rudely......

Comment: I tried to contact the sender but his Phone was off and he block me from Whatsapp. Then I got to know I got scammed. Then I contact DHL for help at no moment of time and the shittest thing is that they don't even understand the situation, and were not even willing to listen. I almost made 10-time calls so I can talk with some sensible but I got nobody and they keep saying to contact the Police. I said, I will do but I am calling you because you have 1000 from me, Please do not send it to Sender, till I make a complaint and they said we can not help you with that...........

Comment: I said if the sender got money there hell no way he got caught because he use a fake DHL Account, a fake address, a fake number might fake Paypal everything fake. there is only a 5% chance he will be got caught. but there 100% way DHL could save my money just call to sender and ask we have some kind of problem with shipping. i know the scammer will not contact to DHL because if he will do he will be got caught but hell no wayyyy. they just keep saying we can not help you sorry contact the Police.Then I made Complaint to Police with no waste of time give them all proof..............

Comment: and they took the parcel into custody. I really hope they will arrest scammer and recover my money. But if they could not find anything. I am pretty sure I am going to Sue a case against DHL in Customer Court and let them know how Protection for Sender and Reciepent suppose to work. 

Comment: @user253751 Yes you are right